# Opencv: Working with 16bit image, Uint16

Tags: c#, image, opencv, ushort

I have a 12bit image that I want to work with in Opencv, such as detecting blobs etc.

The image is now a Uint16 array. And i want to convert it to Opencv Mat or Iplimage. I need to do that inorder to threshold and detect blobs.

What im doing is to convert the ushort array to bitmap, and then to Mat using opencv extensions, see below.

```
ushort[,] red = new ushort  [480,640];
//Grab image in to ushort array
//..
 bmpred = U16ArrayToBitmap(red);
 Mat redMat = new Mat();
 redMat = OpenCvSharp.Extensions.BitmapConverter.ToMat(bmpred);
```

Now redMat, my Mat image is U8C4, as I understand its 4 Chanel Unsigned 8 bit. 
This wont work for me, because I want to use all of the 12 bits!

Is it possible to convert a ushort array or a bitmap into a 16bit grayscale Mat or iplimage?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Mat` constructor directly:

```
var mat = new Mat(red.GetLength(0), red.GetLength(1), MatType.CV_16UC1, red);
```

Or use a `MatOfUShort`:

```
var mat = new MatOfUShort(red.GetLength(0), red.GetLength(1), red);
```

Note that `mat` is using a pointer to `red` array. Clone `mat` if you want to use a copy:

```
var clone = mat.Clone();
```

For more information check [Mat - The Basic Image Container](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/core/mat_the_basic_image_container/mat_the_basic_image_container.html#mat-the-basic-image-container) OpenCV documentation page and [OpenCvSharp Wiki](https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp/wiki).